# f:convertNumber silently converts invalid numbers like 1a to 1 without showing conversion error message

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, numbers, converters

I try to check if an input text is a Integer or not. I have wrote this piece of code:

```
<h:inputText id="amount" value="#{receipt.amount}" required="true" converterMessage="error" requiredMessage="error" validatorMessage="error" >
<f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="#{receipt.all}" />
   <f:convertNumber IntegerOnly="true" />
</h:inputText>
```

and it is working but in one case if I put for example "1a" it converts me this to "1". How can I check this in JSF? I would like to see a message if input is incorrect. I have made validation in my bean and everything worked but I have to do in JSF. Could anybody explain how to set `maximum="#{receipt.all}` correct? If I put in this way I have a zero. I try to refres this input but it didn't work.

Comment: You'd better remove the `<f:validateLongRange>` part and put it in its own question without `<f:convertNumber>` issue. You're supposed to ask one question per Question.

Comment: Thank you for response. I will follow your advice. Do you have any idea how to solve a problem with validation string like "1a"? Is there any chance to do it in JSF?